# C++ Play multiple WAVE resource files at once

Tags: c++, audio, embedded-resource, wave

I am currently working on a C++ text adventure game that will require both background music and SFX. I hope to release the build as a single .exe, which would use Resource Files (.rc) to contain the sounds being played.

I've tried the PlaySound() method but that only allows for one sound to be played from a resource, is there any way to play multiple resource file audios at once?

Answer (score 0):

Playing sounds is not a C++ language feature. It appears you're referring to the Windows API? `PlaySound` wasn't designed for that. You can't do what you want unless you either mix all your audio yourself with e.g. [`waveOutWrite` and friends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743876(v=vs.85).aspx) or [WASAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455(v=vs.85).aspx), or use a more full-featured API like e.g. [SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345328/how-to-output-multiple-sounds-with-sdl) or something.